# Failed to start namenode. Directory is in an inconsistent state: storage directory does not exist or is not accessible

Tags: hadoop, cloudera-cdh

I use the CDH（Cloudera Distribution Hadoop）
when I start the hdsf ,there is no namenode

```
  $ sbin/start-dfs.sh
```

jps:

```
 hadoop@hekuang:~/app/hadoop-2.6.0-cdh5.7.0/sbin$ jps
10489 DataNode
10685 SecondaryNameNode
11469 Jps
```

and the namenode log like that

```
2018-04-22 15:18:48,062 ERROR org.apache.hadoop.hdfs.server.namenode.NameNode: Failed to start namenode.
org.apache.hadoop.hdfs.server.common.InconsistentFSStateException: Directory /home/hadoop/app/tmp/dfs/name is in an inconsistent state: storage directory does not exist or is not accessible.
    at org.apache.hadoop.hdfs.server.namenode.FSImage.recoverStorageDirs(FSImage.java:314)
    at org.apache.hadoop.hdfs.server.namenode.FSImage.recoverTransitionRead(FSImage.java:202)
    at org.apache.hadoop.hdfs.server.namenode.FSNamesystem.loadFSImage(FSNamesystem.java:1063)
    at org.apache.hadoop.hdfs.server.namenode.FSNamesystem.loadFromDisk(FSNamesystem.java:767)
    at org.apache.hadoop.hdfs.server.namenode.NameNode.loadNamesystem(NameNode.java:609)
    at org.apache.hadoop.hdfs.server.namenode.NameNode.initialize(NameNode.java:670)
    at org.apache.hadoop.hdfs.server.namenode.NameNode.<init>(NameNode.java:838)
    at org.apache.hadoop.hdfs.server.namenode.NameNode.<init>(NameNode.java:817)
    at org.apache.hadoop.hdfs.server.namenode.NameNode.createNameNode(NameNode.java:1538)
    at org.apache.hadoop.hdfs.server.namenode.NameNode.main(NameNode.java:1606)
2018-04-22 15:18:48,066 INFO org.apache.hadoop.util.ExitUtil: Exiting with status 1
2018-04-22 15:18:48,068 INFO org.apache.hadoop.hdfs.server.namenode.NameNode: SHUTDOWN_MSG:
```

core-site.xml

```
<configuration>
    <property>
        <name>fs.defaultFS</name>
        <value>hdfs://hekuang:8020</value>
    </property>
<property>
        <name>hadoop.tmp.dir</name>
        <value>/home/hadoop/app/tmp</value>
    </property>
</configuration>
```

hdfs-site.xml

```
<configuration>

<property>
        <name>dfs.replication</name>
        <value>1</value>
    </property>
</configuration>
```

I try to  remove /home/hadoop/app/tmp   ,and restart ,tbut also no namenode.

If  remove

```
<property>
    <name>hadoop.tmp.dir</name>
    <value>/home/hadoop/app/tmp</value>
</property>
```

from core-site.xml，and use the default Directory
 then there has namenode and  no DataNode

Comment: Please add output of `ls -laR /home/hadoop/` to the question... By the way, Hadoop 2.6 & CDH 5.7.0 are kinda old. CDH is currently at 5.14.0, and there are VM's available for use. https://www.cloudera.com/developers/get-started-with-hadoop-tutorial.html

Answer (score 1):

Try this:

1. rm -rf /home/hadoop/app/tmp/*
2. hadoop namenode -format
3. Start Hadoop services !!! start-all.sh

Hope this helps !!! Cheers !!!

Comment: I try it more than once .but stil no name node.
that is why i sak for help

Comment: It would be great if you can share core-site.xml, hdfs-site.xml and NameNode log file to understand the root cause !

Comment: core-site.xml
```
<configuration>
    <property>
        <name>fs.defaultFS</name>
        <value>hdfs://hekuang:8020</value>
    </property>
<property>
        <name>hadoop.tmp.dir</name>
        <value>/home/hadoop/app/tmp</value>
    </property>
</configuration>
```
 hdfs-site.xml 
 ```              
<configuration>

<property>
        <name>dfs.replication</name>
        <value>1</value>
    </property>
</configuration>
```

Comment: the  core-site.xml, hdfs-site.xml and NameNode log   add in the QUESTION